# Wordpress media library appears to be empty 4.5.3

Tags: php, wordpress

we had a wordpress migration but after the migration the media library didn't work anymore, well atleast the front-ended part. All the images are still loading on the website.

It looks like i can still upload images to the server, and i can see them in the FTP but not in the media library. The internet is full off outdated wordpress posts, sites and video's, so i hope i have some better luck here.

Here is what i already tried:

1. checking and changing the file permissions in the FTP
2. reinstalling wordpress(updates menu and then reinstall)
3. checking all my plugins if the are causing the problem

I am running wordpress 4.5.3, and here is a screenshot of the media library.
[image: empty library]

Comment: So even new images you upload don't show up?

Comment: Nope, they just don't show up, but when i access the folders with my FTP program, i can see that it is uploaded.

Comment: And does it matter whether you're using grid view or list view? Any client side errors in the developer console? How about server-side errors? Sounds like something could be wrong with the posts and/or postmeta tables in the database.

Comment: I'm having this issue now, any resolution?

Comment: I guess wordpress was broken(suprise). But it was only the gridview on my instance. Once i started using the listview it showed my content again! But i never got the gridview to work again.